# ANT target if, then, else if, else

Tags: list, ant, equals, sequential, incremental-build

I am so very green and new to ANT and have been searching online for an example similar to this to compare for validity but cannot find anything.  Thanks in advance for you input.

Can you tell me if it is valid to append _old to arg1?

```
    <for list="${file1.list}" param="file1.property">
        <sequential>
            <if>
                <equals arg1="${@{file1.property}_old}" arg2="${@{file1.property}}"/>
                <then>
                    <!--<echo message="Property @{file1.property} has no change "/>-->
                </then>
```

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend avoiding ant-contrib entirely. Reliance on it will cause headaches in the long run. I might be able to help you out if you explain what you're trying to do here from a higher level perspective.

Comment: the compare is to evaluate two property files; if there was an update to the file to only build jars that have updates.

Comment: Have you tried using Ant's `uptodate` task? It might be exactly what you're looking for. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html

Comment: Also, Ant has a `different` selector that enables you to create a fileset of differing files all in one step https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#differentselect